# What is the point of using bare raise in Python

Tags: python, exception, raise

I am trying to understand [this code](https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/blob/master/instapy/like_util.py#L202) and the use of the following pattern:

```
try: 
  ...
except Exception:
  raise
```

What is the point of re-raising the exception like this? Don't you get the same result if you remove the whole try-except block?

Comment: To me that looks like a placeholder that the author either meant to fill in, or intends to fill in later.

Comment: I agree with @G.Anderson.  I've done this as a reminder to revisit a problem, usually with a comment though. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that code achieves nothing.